# What does "protect this backup" in Titanium Backup do?

Tags: titanium-backup

After creating a backup, there is the option "protect this backup". What exactly does this do and when should it be used?

Comment: Raw guess (as I've never used this feature): Keep TiBu from deleting it once the limit of generations is reached? I.e. if you told TiBu to keep 3 backups per app, when creating the 4th it would remove the 1st. But if you protected the 1st, it instead would remove the 2nd – the 1st would be "kept forever".

Comment: What they said... It could also password protect the backup with some method of encryption and md5

Comment: @user157947 there is a different option for encryption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Discovered one more feature of TiBu. Wiki (Titanium track) does not explicitly mention what it does and searching net gave clues pretty much aligned to [Izzy's comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155234/what-does-protect-this-backup-do#comment198795_155234)

Most likely [use case](http://androidforums.com/threads/sprint-can-anyone-use-the-protect-backups-feature-in-titanium-backup-pro.574010/)

> .... protect backups of certain apps that have gotten worse with an update. This keeps my "good" backup from being overwritten when my schedule runs.

Implementation of this seems to have a troublesome history as can be seen [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2059240) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2349460&page=2) apart from the above post which quotes the use case and several others of similar nature. Cursory reading reveals that:

1. It was initially meant only for devices not having external SD card
2. Initially worked only on FAT 32
3. Above coupled with *read- write* permission changes across Android versions made the implementation shaky
4. There were issues at different points of times in *protecting* and *unprotecting* app
5. Change log of app reveals, it was dropped as added later, and modified

As it stands it works on my device (rooted), running 6.0.1 with backups stored on external SD.

**What does it do?**

TiBu permits you to have a maximum backup history ranging from 1 to 50 (Preferences → Maximum Backup History ). On my device it is configured to 7. When I *protect* any version of an app it creates a kind of master version which is not counted for the 7- that means the *protected* version stays and with subsequent backups, old backups are deleted new ones added subject to ceiling of 7

**Edit** I just noticed (27/12/19) that one can have more than one protected backups! I was somehow under the impression that protected backup can only be one but with version 1.3.2, I was able to create 3 protected backups of an app whereas the maximum backup is set to 2

**Protecting App**

Select the desired app by short pressing and follow steps below

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Unprotecting App**

Simply the reverse of above

[image]
[image]

Comment: Good question, awesome answer. That's what I thought, intuitively, surprised to learn that this option changed many times. The current definition you explained makes a lot of sense to me.